# Restoring CVS repository using working directory

Tags: cvs, restore

I have deleted a module (an entire project) in CVS repository. I'm unable to restore the files. But I have checked out the modules to my local which is the HEAD revision.
Is there any way I can rebuild the project in CVS repository with my working repository?

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what you removed.

If you deleted the modules on the server file system, then you need to recover the directory structure from a backup. If there is no backup, the only thing you can do is it import your local checkout as a new module, but the entire history is gone (CVS checkouts are very dumb, they don't even contain the pristine copies of the checked out files).

If you deleted the module with the `cvs remove`, then the files are still on the server, but are moved into the `attic` directories there.